# R Randomforest undefined column issue

Tags: r, random-forest, text-mining

I am working on a text mining process and using Random forest to classify text to categories.
I am using caret package after processing my text.
I split the data to train and test,
Below is the R code after the same:

```
traindata <- tdm_df[s,] # training set

testdata <- tdm_df[-s,] # testing set

rf.tfidf <- train(traindata[,c(1:69)], train[,70],
                  method = "rf", trControl = ctrl) # train random forest
rf.tfidf
```

When I run the last line, I get the below error:

```
Error in `[.data.frame`(train, , c(1:56)) : undefined columns selected
```

Edit 1: next error after correction:
 `Error in train[1:5, ] : object of type 'closure' is not subsettable`

I see the term_sparse is giving me an issue and may be the text mining part, how can i improve my outcome?

Not sure what the issue is.
Please help out!

Comment: What is the result of `dim(train)`?

Comment: [1] 693   5, i see the issue now but i dont see why, I should get atleast 50 terms. can you please help me?, ive added the full code in the question edit. @kath

Comment: Probably because of this statement: `tdm_sparse <- removeSparseTerms(tdm, 0.90)` Columns/ Sparse Words are removed.

Comment: First of all, do not give objects the same name as functions. so no `train` for your training data. Second, method `rpart` is not selecting randomForest, but recursive partitioning. You need method `rf`. Check if your training data actually has 57 columns. We don't have access to the notes data, please use the crude dataset that comes with tm to make a fully reproducible example.

Comment: @phiver, noted, ill make the necessary changes. Ive added the first 20 rows as dput output in the queestion, it it helps you understand my data. please help me out.

Comment: but if i dont use sparse terms, the words arent getting split as terms but shows `sbpmtrdb status tazrjdpmmdb tra warning cpu currently high utilization ......` @tushaR how do i correct it? should i change the 0.90 to a diff value?

Comment: `tdm_sparse <- removeSparseTerms(tdm, 0.90)` removes the sparse terms which do not occur in 90% of the documents/rows. Hence, I think after removal of the sparse terms you are only left with 5 terms. You can play around with the threshold value of .90 and increase it to get more number of columns.
As far as the error message `Error in [.data.frame(train, , c(1:56)) : undefined columns selected` is concerned: You are trying to build a model on a `data.frame` containing 56 columns which do not exist as shared by you. (693,5). What is your target or dependent variable? Share `dput(train[1:20,])`

Comment: my dependent variable is the category, which im trying to predict with the description given post this. I tried around with the parse terms and managed to get more terms, but when im executing rf.tfidf, im getting `Error in train[, 100] : object of type 'closure' is not subsettable` @tushaR please help me with this

Comment: added with the question, please check @tushaR

Comment: Can you join this chat room? https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/199432/room-for-tushar-and-spishere

Comment: @tushaR, I have!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Replace `train[,70]` with `traindata[,70]`:

```
rf.tfidf <- train(traindata[,c(1:69)], traindata[,70],
              method = "rf", trControl = ctrl)
```